# Create an element similar to the element I have (including the content and the style)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have 'DIV' element, and when I click on the button, I want get the same 'DIV' on the page (including the content, the style and the images it has).

that is the code I tryed:

HTML:

```
            <div id="taskId">
                <p id="taskWritten">
                        the task will written here
                </p>
            </div>
            <button id="button">add item</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
let button = document.querySelector('#button');
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        let task = document.querySelector('#taskId');
        let newTask = document.createElement(task);
        document.appendChild(newTask);
})
```

this code doesn't work.
Can anyone explain to me where my error is?
(I am an absolute beginner with programming)

Comment: what is going wrong?

Comment: "similar" to the element, or an exact clone? Be careful, you are using `id`s which are required to be unique within the DOM. If you duplicate that div you will have two `id="taskId"` and two `id="taskWritten"` Possibly you should use _classes_ for those instead of an `id` ... this is **a** taskId, not **the** (one and only) taskId, maybe like `<div class="taskId" data-taskid="42">`

Comment: `document.createElement()` expects a string(tag name) and not a DOM object

Comment: So what should I use? any feedback will help me

Comment: "What should I use?" — see Chaim Friedman's answer, which is The Right Way™ to do this.

Comment: You may also want to read about [The Content Template element](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) which exists to be cloned.

Comment: OK I will read it.

Comment: Should I use it for that "querySelectorAll" or "getElementByClassName"?

Comment: _"Should I use"_ ... There are whole debates (some here on Stackoverflow) about using `querySelectorAll` vs `getElementByClassName` — it often doesn't matter, but they _do_ return different things; a `NodeList` for querySelectorAll vs. an  `HTMLCollection` for getElementsByClassname. Google "queryselectorall vs getelementsbyclassname" and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but need to only make minor changes. The code should look like this.

```
let task = document.querySelector('#taskId');
const newTask = task.cloneNode(true);
document.appendChild(newTask);
```

here you are creating a new node which will model your original node entirely including the style and data

Comment: Yes, upvote, but OP @Chani and other readers should be aware that the newly cloned element will have duplicate `id` names, which is invalid. See the note in MDN's [Node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode#Notes) documentation _"**Warning:** cloneNode() may lead to duplicate element IDs in a document!"_

Comment: this is a good point. Ideally the an id should need be used here.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a 'div' with 'createElement'. You can use the code below with some adjustments.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#button');
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        task=document.querySelector('#taskId');
        let newTask = document.createElement('div');
        newTask.innerHTML='<div><p>the task will written here</p></div>'
        task.appendChild(newTask);
})
```

```html
<div id="taskId">
  <p id="taskWritten">
    the task will written here
  </p>
</div>
<button id="button">add item</button>
```